# Hide Bootstrap Datepicker after changing month

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to hide datepicker after changing month. For that I tried this code :

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    viewMode: 'months',
    format: 'mm-yyyy'
    }).on('changeMonth', function (e){
      $(this).datepicker('hide');
    });
```

But it's not working, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  startView: 'months',
  minViewMode: 'months',
  format: 'mm-yyyy'
}).on('changeMonth', function(e) {
  $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it Is it working ? but on my side it's not working

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for it?

Comment: your code is correct but i don't want like this actually I want to hide datepicker after selecting month not after selecting date that's why I used 'changeMonth' event in my code

Comment: Perfect ! Just like I wanted rep +1 Thank you very much